# Проблема загрузки данных на Бэкенд

Tags: reactjs

у меня такая проблема.
(Все это происходит после авторизации на сайте)
Пытаюсь сделать добавление новой записи на странице, но при клике на кнопку "Добавить запись"
страница просто перезагружается и в url рядом с названием роута появляется вопросительный знак, а добавления не происходит, даже если смотреть в базе данных никакого добавления не случается.
Однако сервер работает хорошо, если делать запрос через Postman в таком случае добавление происходит и базе данных отображаются все данные которые я только что добавил через Postman.
Подскажите что я делаю не так?
Почему страница просто перезагружается и ничего не происходит?
даже в консоли не бывает ошибок.

P.S: Стек Node.js, Express, MongoDB
Заранее спасибо за помощь!)

вот сам запрос на добавление, на клиентской части.

```
export const AddFeed = (feed) => {
 return async dispatch => {
  dispatch({type: 'auth/feed/pending'})

  const response = await fetch('/feed', {
   method:'POST',
   body:  feed,
   headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
   }
  });

  const json = await response.json();

  if (json.error) {
   dispatch({type:'auth/feed/rejected', error: json.error})
  }else {
   dispatch({type:'auth/feed/fulfilled', payload: json})
  }
 }
}
```

код самой кнопки jsx.

```
 const dispatch = useDispatch(); 
    const [text, setText] = useState(''); 
    const handleAddFeed = () => {
     dispatch(AddFeed(text))
     } 
    const handleOnChangeFeed = (e) => {
     setText(e.target.value) 
    }
     return ( 
    <div>
     <form style={{marginTop:'30px', display:'flex'}}> 
    <input 
    className="form-control" 
    type="text"
     value={text}
     onChange={handleOnChangeFeed} 
    placeholder="Что у вас нового?" />
     <button
    className="form-control" 
    onClick={handleAddFeed}>
     Добавить запись
     </button> 
    </form> 
    </div>
     );
```

Comment: Дайте jsx код самой кнопки

Comment: Лучше бы вы конечно добавили код в сам вопрос.

Comment: Скорее всего выполняется стандартная браузерная отправка формы. Чтобы предотвратить это, допишите к кнопке атрибут `type="button"`

Comment: в таком случае он говорит, bad request

Comment: @LinkBronks значит вы внутри функции AddFeed передаёте что-то неправильное — например, забыли закодировать feed в JSON-формат